# Default scanner settings in Windows 10 for all users

Tags: windows-10, scanner

This is my first post here so apologies in advance for any breaches in etiquette...

My organisation is using OCR software to scan in forms using Kodak scanners to capture data (on Windows 10). The default settings for the Kodak scanner (TWAIN driver) are set to black and white, but this causes problems with reading barcodes due to the shoddy resolution especially if the barcode is stuck on at an angle.

To fix this issue you can change the settings to Greyscale, but the problem is when a new user logs in, the scanner reverts back to the default. We have more users than we do scanner workstations, and it's a pain to keep having to adjust the settings on each machine for each new user.

Do any of you kind people know anything about how Windows 10 handles user profiles, specifically where the scanning defaults are kept for the TWAIN driver, or any idea how to create a new default that applies to any user who logs in?

I've been to the developers of both the scanning software (Chronoscan) and Kodak. Kodak claim it's down to the scanning application, but i contest that you can replicate this behaviour without ever launching Chronoscan i.e. new user logs into a PC, starts up the scanner, is presented with the same scan settings window as the one invoked by Chronoscan, and default settings are back to black & white.

The settings are retained if a user has previously logged in and changed them, so it must be storing this somewhere but i can't find it :(

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Have you tried to configure it through a group policy?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/printing/use-group-policy-to-control-ad-printer)

Comment: Which scanner model has this behavior?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i've been busy with other stuff...  to answer the first question, i don't have access to group policy settings at work but can ask our main IT dept to make changes.  It's a Kodak / Alaris S2070.  Thanks